# How to make current environment as image docker in ubunu 14.04?

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu-14.04, lxc

I have ubuntu 14.04 and installed node.js and many modules recently.
How can I create docker image that have current environment (the image has to use installed node.js in the ubnutu 14.04 and all its modules) without installing nodejs and modules on new Image.

Comment: Create a base image with nodejs and your required modules installed. Then use this image in your application Dockerfiles.

Comment: I can do that. But node and many of the modules were already installed in my system. Is there any way to use existing programs in all images without being installed.

Comment: Docker will not use software installed on your host machine by design. That is the purpose of creating a base image, containing the shared dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. [Docker Commit](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#commit) the current image and then push it to a repository as your base image.
2. Use a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) to repeat the steps you have done manually to create your base image.

You can then use [`FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#from) in your downstream images to get the current state without having to rebuild it. Option 2 is preferred as you can see exactly how an image was created and easily make changes.

Comment: I am new to docker. can you please give me the dockerfile for my requirement.

Comment: Here is a docker file for a nodejs service that I use called Uptime. It should give you a fair idea of how to make your own. https://github.com/techtraits/docker-uptime/blob/master/Dockerfile